# Hide tabs based on permission from JSON data

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of JSON output. Each value in the list has a string which corresponds to a tab name.

I have to iterate through the JSON list and hide all the tabs with are not there in the list.

Example : If the actual page has TabA, TabB, Tabc and my json output has TabA and TabB, then TabC should be hidden.

How to achive this functionality.  Here is the scenario which I need to implement,

```
{
"permission": [{
    "add": "true",
    "delete": "false",
    "edit": "false",
    "function": "Claims Management ",
    "tab": "Claims Management ",
    "view": "true"
}, {
    "add": "true",
    "delete": "true",
    "edit": "true",
    "function": "Collections ",
    "tab": "Collections ",
    "view": "true"
}]
}
```

This is the JSON output. I have to show only these two tabs and hide the others.

Thanks in advance,
Pritam

Comment: In Js, check the `length` of `tab C`. If not present then hide tab c. `e.g if(data.tabC.length <= 0){$('#tabC').hide()}`.

Comment: Thanks Samir, 
Here is the scenario which I need to implement,

{
"permission": [2]
0:  {
"add": "true"
"delete": "false"
"edit": "false"
"function": "Claims Management "
"tab": "Claims Management "
"view": "true"
}-
1:  {
"add": "true"
"delete": "true"
"edit": "true"
"function": "Collections "
"tab": "Collections "
"view": "true"
}-
-
}

This is the JSON output.
i have to show only these two tabs and hide the others.

Comment: The json which you have provided is incorrect. I have attached in your question. Let me know is that correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

Case when your page come with content(tabs) initially and unknown number of tabs and the content(tabs) it's not inserted according to json regulation

**on document.ready iterate through permission and

`if (!permission[i].view){
//get the element like 
 $each(".tabs",function(){
  if($(this).text()==="tabC") {
     $(this).hide();
  }
 })
}`

-that's not the optimal, or fastest way to do it but it's a start